# Passing variables/values to custom exception?

Tags: php

Is this how you would pass a value ("username" in example below) to a custom exception? The question being Would I use `__construct()`? Is using a custom exception for checking whether an important variable is set an overkill?

```
class customException extends Exception {

    public function __construct($e) {
        parent::__construct($e); // makes sure variable is set? [1]
        $this->e = $e;
    }
    public function redirect_user() {
        if($this->e === "username") {
            header("Location: ");
        }
    }
}

class testing {

    public function test() {
        try {
            if(!isset($_POST['username'])) {
                throw new customException("username");
            }
        }
        catch(customException $e) {
            $e->redirect_user();
        }
    }
}
```

[1] http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php#example-266

On a side note, what's the purpose of `parent::__construct($e)`? Wouldn't that be redundant?

Comment: `parent::__construct($e)` is used to include the extended class constructor. If you don't use it the extended class (Exception) constructor  is overwritten.

Comment: @Deepak can you dumb it down for me just a tad? :) What is `__construct()` overriding?

Comment: They are better ways to handle if a variable is set than throw exceptions

Comment: @Baba okay... thanks for letting me know there are better ways. could you elaborate?

Comment: Just a tip: There normally is no need for an exception to take care about the redirect. That's not how Exceptions work. Move the redirect in some other class.

Comment: @hakre okay thanks! I will research more on the correct uses for exceptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason for your constructor at all.  I would suggest using `$this->getMessage()` to access the value you are trying to set to `$this->e`.

So do something like this:

```
class customException extends Exception {
    public function redirect_user() {
        if($this->getMessage() === "username") {
            print_r("Header");
        }
    }
}
```

It is much more straightforward and only extends the functionality of the base class rather than unnecessarily overriding the constructor.

That being said, I personally don't like the thought of using exceptions to execute application flow logic like you are doing. To me, custom Exceptions are useful to interface with custom logging systems, or to be able to log aspects of your application's state that are not available via the default Exception class.

Comment: Thanks, this is the correct answer. Could you really quickly explain what your last paragraph means? :O How would you have handled this?

Comment: @Adam184 What I mean is that Exceptions, whether custom or standard, are typically only used in most applications for purposes of alerting/logging, which might include gathering of application state (call stack, memory usage, session status, etc.), not for application flow logic (i.e. redirecting users to new pages or similar).  It would be very unorthodox from a application design standpoint to use Exceptions in the way which you are proposing to use it

Comment: @Adam184 In your case, I might have just thrown an exception and then actually performed the `header()` redirection explicitly in the catch block, rather than trying to make a custom Exception which performs the redirection.  That being said, that are always exceptions to the "rules" or "best practices" in programming which only you as the developer would have the full understanding for whether your needs call for such an approach.